# Accessing Private Fields Of Superclass in SubClass

Tags: java, inheritance, super

```
package com.company;


import java.util.Scanner;

class Person{
    private String name;
    String address;


    public Person() {


        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
    public Person(String name, String address) {


        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
class Student extends Person{
    String program;
    int year;
    double fee;
    //public Student(){super();};


    public Student(String program, int year, double fee){
        super.Person(name,address); <----Error is here

        this.program = program;
        this.fee = fee;
        this.year = year;

    }
```

IT IS GIVING ME ERROR THAT NAME IS PRIVATE. I HAVE TRIED ADDING AND REMOVING DEFAULT CONSTRUCTORS BUT NOTHING HELPED
I have tried playing with constructors but nothing helped.

Comment: You can't acces private fields outside of the declaring class. But why you want to set the name of the super class to the super class?

Answer (score 0):

Your Student class shouldn't be defined within the Person class.  And `name` isn't defined within Student where you're trying to access it, so it tries to access the `name` property of the superclass, which is private and outside of Student's scope.

You should define Student outside of Person, and add `name` and `address` parameters to its constructor.